# Access local website without dns?

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, ip, load-balancing, hostname

I got an nginx loadbalancer setup with 2 sites. The ip address of the loadbalancer is 192.168.123.10
I want to locally access the two sites to check if everything is working. 
But I'm a little puzzled about hostnames and domainnames.
I have given the first site the hostname: "test" and a domain name of "mytest.local". I read in the manual that if I want to access the site, I should go to test.mytest.local and make the dns for that address point to the IP of the loadbalancer.

But I don't understand how my computer will know which site I want, because if my other site I loadbalance is anothertest.mytest.local and it resolves to the same IP, how will this be different?

I haven't set up any dns, I just want to check if the nginx is working, so can i still access the website test.mytest.local locally?  (without setting up a dns)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, editting `/etc/hosts` like this:

```
192.168.0.10 example.com.local
```

That file is where it checks first when you are trying to resolve any hostname, then it goes ahead and uses DNS servers. I'm saying this so you are aware that, for example, if you add `1.2.3.4 google.com` to `/etc/hosts`, you wont be able to get to the real `google.com`

Comment: Yes, that's true. Can I also use postman and do a get on 192.168.123.39 and set my host: example in the body?

Comment: Not sure about how postman works, sorry

Comment: Okay thank you, but it works I guess. The problem is, it's still showing the nginx home page instead of the actual page :(

Answer (score 0):

"NGINX Server Blocks" seems to be what you are looking for.

Web clients (i.e. Firefox or Chrome) send the intended URL to the web server, hence web servers can provide different sites on the same IP based on the "name" the web browser is using to access it.

Take a look at this example configuration from [this NGINX page](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/), it is quite self-explanatory:

```
http {
  index index.html;

  server {
    server_name www.domain1.com;
    access_log logs/domain1.access.log main;

    root /var/www/domain1.com/htdocs;
  }

  server {
    server_name www.domain2.com;
    access_log  logs/domain2.access.log main;

    root /var/www/domain2.com/htdocs;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this way, you can access [www.domain1.com](http://www.domain1.com) through same machine. But in my case I want to access [www.domain1.com](http://www.domain1.com) through different machine, connected locally in the same network.

By accessing [www.domain1.com](http://www.domain1.com) through different machine it tries to resolve hosts from different device's "/etc/hosts" file.